# How to assign variable inside CTE

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-server-2019

If I run below script, the print statement will print 10

```
declare @i int = 0

select @i = @i + 2
from sys.tables

print @i
```

But if I want to use the same concept inside CTE, it does not work.

I'm trying to run below T-SQL, but I get error

```
declare @i int = 0

;with ct (x) as
(
    select @i = @i + 2
    from sys.tables
)
select * 
from ct

print @i
```

I get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

My intention is adding up the variable `@i` without while loop.

Comment: This seems like a rather contrived example. Why not simply use an aggregate function instead of an incrementing variable?

Comment: This is part of a bigger problem and there are reasons that I need to do it this way.

Comment: You can't. End of story. You can only assign a variable at the final `SELECT`, and you can't return a data set and assign in the same statement. This is definitely an XY Problem what is the actual problem you're Try Ng to solve here?

Comment: @FLICKER - Explain the bigger problem.  There's usually a solution to this type of thing but you've presupposed a partial solution that may not be the best one.